# How to create datatype references using array length-java

Tags: java, arrays

In a string i have an method signature eg: `String methSign = "public int add(int a, int b){ }"`,
then i have obtained the array of parameter list using `String` methods.
Now how to create the corresponding array element dataType references...

Comment: You are parsing a string that looks like a method declaration? Are you trying to reimplement a Java compiler or analyzer? Unless this is homework (and you should tag it as such), it is almost certainly a bad idea to do this yourself. There are sophisticated open-source solutions that you can simply use.

Comment: Can you please provide a little more information about what you're really trying to do? What is the code you have, and where do you run into problems?

Answer (score 0):

If you have are stuck on what Java method signatures are allowed to look like, check out the [related section in the Java language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2).

If you aren't sure how to parse a certain string, you'll need to post a more detailed question including the input string / array, your code, what you expected to get and what you actually got.
Some good starting points for string parsing in Java are:

- [Apache Commons StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)
- Guava [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) / [Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html)